# Guice + Jersey + Spring data

Tags: jersey, spring-data, guice

I am planning to use Guice(for DI) and Jersey( for rest). They integrate very well but I also want to leverage what spring-data provides. But it seems like we need to integrate spring first to use Spring data*. Is there any way i can integrate spring-data* without using spring ioc container.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. I did it. it seems spring data related beans should be manually wired.

Comment: would it be possible to share some pointers on how to do that?